# How to use libgit's git_repository_open in d

Tags: d, libgit2

I am trying to use the [libgit2](https://github.com/s-ludwig/libgit2) library in d. I always get a segmentation fault upon the the program's exit. The error does not happen before the exit, when I open and close the repository. It would seem that this is an issue with the garbage collector, but manually disabling the garbage collector (GC.disable();) seems to not effect the outcome at all. Freeing (git_repository_free(repo)) also seems to have no effect.

This some example code:

```
import std.stdio : writeln;
import std.string : toStringz;

import core.memory : GC;

import deimos.git2.types : git_repository;
import deimos.git2.repository : git_repository_open, git_repository_free;

void main() {
    GC.disable();
    git_repository *repo;
    git_repository_open(&repo, ".".toStringz());
    git_repository_free(repo);
    writeln("END");
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./gittest
END
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./gittest
```

The versions:

- libgit2-dev: 0.22.1-0ubuntu3
- libgit2: ~>0.20.1
- dub: 0.9.23-0
- dmd-bin: 2.067.1-0
- kubuntu: 15.04

What, if anything, am I doing wrong? And if nothing can the culprit of the bug be identified (d, libgit2, or the libgit2 d bindings)?

Additional note: I tried working with dlibgit and found it to be incredibly buggy, mostly to being outdated it would seem. This question refers to the libgit2 d bindings.

Comment: libgit2 0.22.1 requires a call to [`git_libgit2_init`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#initialization) before any other libgit2 functions are called. As the D bindings are for 0.20.1, they don't provide a binding to this function. This _might_ be the issue. I'll dig around some more.

Comment: You are correct. This was the issue. Adding `extern (C):

int git_libgit2_init();
int git_libgit2_shutdown();` and using the functions fix the code. I shall leave the formal answer to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoted from my comment:

libgit2 0.22.1 requires a call to [git_libgit2_init](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#initialization) before any other libgit2 functions are called. As the D bindings are for 0.20.1, they don't provide a binding to this function.

You can hack in bindings to the init/shutdown functions with:

```
extern (C):
int git_libgit2_init();
int git_libgit2_shutdown();
```